# Access Firebase unique ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing comment form data to a firebase realtime database using `push`. I have a function watching for the `onWrite` event to capture comments posted.

Here's my function:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.newComment = functions.database.ref('{postRef}')
  .onWrite(event => {
    console.log("Started!");
    return theComment(event.data);
  });

function theComment(snapshot) {
  console.log("Running theComment");
  var comment = snapshot._delta;
  console.log(comment);
}
```

The returned tree is:

```js
{ '-L10TQfRr9IFhOsd1nJe': 
   { md5Email: '93942e96f5acd83e2e047ad8fe03114d',
     message: 'This is a test post.',
     moderated: false,
     name: 'demo',
     postedAt: 1514000728416 } 
}
```

I'd read that the `key` value will return the ID in v3, but when I try to log `comment.key`, it logs `undefined`.

Is there a better way to watch and access the new elements when they're written?

Comment: should be other accessors for the key in `snapshot` ... something like `snapshot.key` or `snapshot.ref.key`

Answer (score 0):

You dont' have property named key in your object comment, inorder to get key, you can use Object.keys

**DEMO**

```js
var comment = { '-L10TQfRr9IFhOsd1nJe': 
   { md5Email: '93942e96f5acd83e2e047ad8fe03114d',
     message: 'This is a test post.',
     moderated: false,
     name: 'demo',
     postedAt: 1514000728416 } 
};

console.log(Object.keys(comment));;
```